# Wh embedded question ambiguous trees

Tags: syntax-trees

I am having problems drawing the trees for the following sentence. I'm interested in both the pre and post movement trees for this ambiguous sentence:

Lisa wondered when Bart said she saw Nelson.

If anyone can help me I would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks